# delete end to line and no new paragraph

Tags: bash, shell, paragraph

I have the following data, and I need to put it all in format paragraph.

```
Don Quixote has inspired many artists
in different fields. It is considered mainly to 
be a comedy. However, woven into the tale is a lot of Spain's 
history. Don Quixote's name even penned a type of psychosis.

In fact, anyone who has had experience with the mentally ill 
may find it difficult to regard Don Quixote as a comedy. After 
all, he was not totally harmless.

"A man attacked a driver because he believed he was abducting a 
woman, who was traveling in another car on the same road. 

After injuring the driver, the suspect's accomplice then 
forced the driver to remove his clothes and give them to 
him"--if this was reported on the news, we would probably 
e horrified. Here was an innocent person, just going about 
his business, who had no connection to the other people who 
were on the same road--and he gets attacked by a madman 
whose delusions cause him to believe a different reality.
```

I need this:

*Don Quixote has inspired many artists in different fields. It is considered mainly to be a comedy. However, woven into the tale is a lot of Spain's history. Don Quixote's name even penned a type of psychosis.*

In fact, anyone who has had experience with the mentally ill may find it difficult to regard Don Quixote as a comedy. After all, he was not totally harmless.

"A man attacked a driver because he believed he was abducting a woman, who was traveling in another car on the same road.

After injuring the driver, the suspect's accomplice then forced the driver to remove his clothes and give them to him"--if this was reported on the news, we would probably be horrified. Here was an innocent person, just going about his business, who had no connection to the other people who were on the same road--and he gets attacked by a madman whose delusions cause him to believe a different reality.

Comment: I assume you want the following, based on your sample output:  flatten each paragraph into a single line by replacing each paragraph-interior newline with a single space. If so, please state this (or your true requirements) explicitly in your question, which would make it specific enough to be a candidate for reopening.

Answer (score 1):

Note: The assumptions is that you want to:

- retain paragraphs in principle
- but flatten each paragraph into a *single* line by replacing each paragraph-interior newline with a single space.

There are several **options**:

- Use `fmt`, as [user1934428's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34149544/45375) suggest, with an *unlimited line length*:

  - The **caveat** is that  `fmt` requires a specific number as the target line length, and with ***GNU* `fmt`** (at least as of coreutils v8.24) that value is capped at `2500`, which may not be large enough, depending on your needs: `fmt -w 2500 file`.
    **BSD `fmt`**, by contrast, apparently accepts arbitrarily large numbers, but I don't know where it cuts off in practice.
- Use `awk`, as demonstrated below.

  - Note: This will normalize any paragraph-internal run of tabs and spaces to a single space each.
- If you install my [whitespace-normalizing `nws` CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nws-cli), you can simply use `nws --fp file`

  - Note: This will normalize any paragraph-internal run of tabs and spaces to a single space each.

---

**`awk` solution**:

```
awk -v RS= '
  BEGIN { OFS=" "; ORS="\n\n" }
  NR > 1 { print "" }
  { $1 = $1; printf "%s", $0 }
  END { printf "\n" }
' file
```

- `-v RS=`, i.e., setting the input-record separator to an empty string, is an Awk idiom that makes Awk consider runs of contiguous non-empty lines - paragraphs - a single record.
- `OFS=" "` sets the output-*field* separator to a single space.
- `ORS="\n\n"` sets the output-*record* separator to 2 newlines.
- `$1 = $1` is a trick to force rebuilding of the input record by joining the fields (which were obtained by splitting the record by any run of whitespace) with `OFS`, which in this case effectively replaces each block-interior newline with a space; `printf "%s", $0` prints the rebuilt line *without* ORS at first (see below).

  - Note: Any run of spaces and/or tabs is also replaced with a single space.
- `NR > 1 { print "" }` delays printing the ORS by one line, so that ORS is not automatically printed at the end, which would result in *2* trailing `\n` chars. `{ printf "\n" }`, in the `END` block, then prints the single trailing `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't

```
fmt file
```

doing what you want to achieve?

Comment: ++ for pointing to `fmt`, but, from what I understand, there should be _no_ limit on the line length, so you'd have to use `fmt -w <largestLineLengthPossible>`,
which limits you to 2500 with _GNU_ `fmt`; BSD `fmt` doesn't enforce such an arbitrary limit, but I haven't tested where it cuts off in practice.